# Javascript: Wrong message returned if the function doesn't exists

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function who can call any function with an error message if the function doesn't exists
I have this function

```
var _call = function()  {
    var methodToCall = arguments[0];
    delete arguments[0];

    try {
        window[methodToCall](arguments);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
};
```

And I call this function like this :

```
_call('getMethod', 'lolo', [0, 1, 2]);
```

It works as I expected excepted if the function is not defined, it displays `window[methodToCall] is not a function` and I'd like to have `functionNotDefined is not a function`

Comment: How about testing `typeof(methodToCall) === 'function'` and logging your own message? Your current catch will catch errors thrown by a function (that *is* a function) as well.

Comment: then don't use the `err.message` value and define your own.

`methodToCall + "is not a function"`

Comment: Biffen ; I tried but I as pass the function name as a string the `typeof()`don't works. Semi-friends, Yes it's a good idea but as I'm not sure thats the only error i'll have to manage I wanted to use the exception message :)

Comment: @Lolo `typeof(window[methodToCall])`, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  _call('foo', 'lolo', [0, 1, 2]);
  // function bar does not exist
  _call('bar', 'lolo', [0, 1, 2]);
}

function foo(a) {
  console.log('called foo, with arguments "' + JSON.stringify(a) +'"');
}

var _call = function()  {
  var methodToCall = arguments[0];
  delete arguments[0];
  if (typeof window[methodToCall] !== 'function') {
    return false;  
  }
  try {
    window[methodToCall](arguments);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};
</script>
```